# Index GATE annotations in SOLR

Tags: solr, gate, behemoth

I need to index all the annotations and features generated after GATE processing into SOLR. I need to search upon annotations as well as features. What is the best way to do this? I would prefer moving processing to hadoop.

I am using behemoth at the moment, but it does not index the annotations and features, it indexes only the text.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.findwise.com/blog/how-to-index-and-search-xml-content-in-solr/ for some ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See answer on the DigitalPebble mailing list where you should ask questions about Behemoth https://groups.google.com/d/msg/digitalpebble/o_6xHtt1rpk/ZdKa6JKcRGIJ

Comment: Thanks! I had asked this question here before asking on the mailing list. I managed to solve it in the same manner just before you replied. Thanks again.